# Extend the 'Quick-edit' Plugin?

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Can i extend the `quick-edit` plugin in jira so that i can do some custom validation on the quick-edit page?
I have tried adding the quiick-edit plugin as a dependency and extending the `QuickEditIssue` class but it is showing the error

> Edit Issue "The JIRA server was contacted but has returned an error
>   response. We are unsure of the result of this operation. Close this
>   dialog and press refresh in your browser"

So is it possible in the first place or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that I've found is to manually edit the source code of the **jira-quick-edit-plugin** (a JIRA system plugin) found in the JIRA 5 sources archive.

You can add your classes that extend the original actions, the original actions being **QuickEditIssue** and **QuickCreateIssue**, then you have to modify the **atlassian-plugin.xml** so that you reference your extended classes rather than the original ones.

After this, you have to package the plugin and replace it with the one found in **atlassian-bundled-plugins.zip** found in the `WEB-INF/classes folder`.

It's not the most elegant solution, but it's the only one I have found so far.

I've asked a similar question on the atlassian answers [site](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/137921/how-to-extend-issue-actions-in-jira-5).